# Почему происходит ошибка "missing return statement" в конструкции try-catch?

Tags: java

У меня есть метод:

```
public static String readString(){
    try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))){
        return bufferedReader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e){
            
    }
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Missing return statement

Comment: Ваша функция ничего не возвращает при ошибке. Откуда вам знать что у вас ошибка при чтении пользовательского ввода?

Comment: Увидел, спасибо

Comment: Кроме того, у вас используется `try-with-resources`, а значит после первого вызова функции буферизованный поток вывода будет закрыт, и соответственно закрыт системный поток `System.in`, который НЕЛЬЗЯ будет переоткрыть без перезапуска программы.  То есть, вы не сможете прочитать больше одной строки из консоли при использовании этого метода.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, буду знать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка `missing return statement` возникает, когда метод, который имеет тип возвращаемого значения (является не `void`),  ничего не возвращает оператором `return`.

**Давайте посмотрим на ваш метод с точки зрения jdk.**

Так, нужно постараться выполнить код в блоке `try`. Есть два варианта: код в блоке `try` выполнится или не выполнится (произойдёт исключение).

**Если код в блоке try выполнится (исключения не произойдёт):**
из метода будет возвращена строка, считанная `BufferedReader`'ом. Всё ок.

**Если код в блоке try не выполнится (произойдёт исклоючение):** программа "перепрыгивает" в блок `catch`. В блоке `catch` ничего не возвращается. Программа будет выполнять метод дальше, но в методе больше ничего нет. И оператора `return`, который должен вернуть значение, тоже нет. А метод должен возвращать строку. Всё плохо, так быть не должно. Вот и причина ошибки.

**Решение проблемы:**

Нужно добавить оператор `return` в блок `catch`. Можно вернуть сообщение об ошибке, например:

```java
} catch (IOException e){
    return "Ошибка! Не удалось считать данные!";
}
```

Но можно сделать даже так:

```java
} catch (IOException e){
    return e.getMessage();
}
```

**P.S:**

В данном случае не нужно использовать `try-with-resources`, про это уже говорил @NowhereMan. Просто используйте **обычный** `try-catch`. И закрывать поток `System.in` не надо:

```java
try {
   BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   return bufferedReader.readLine();
} catch (IOException e){
   return "Ошибка! Проблема при чтении данных!";
}
```